# header of view controller

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using rviz to show the navigation map. Now I want to make the robot always in the middle of the map. I try to avoid plugin. So I try to use Viewcontroller::lookat and VisualizationManager::getCurrentViewController.
But I am always wrong about the header and I don't know whether I can do this without using plugin (because I think plugin is too complicated).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211662/header-of-view-controller/) by [YiboLyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22847/yibolyu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Set the "target frame" to be the frame of the robot (commonly named `/base_link`) and the camera will move with that link and therefore the robot.

This will only follow the position of the robot, but will not turn with it. There is an open pull request that adds a new view controller to rviz which also follows in a "third person" mode:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/861

I haven't had time to integrate it yet, but you might be able to build rviz with that pull request merged in the mean time.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YiboLyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22847/yibolyu/) on 2015-06-18**:
Thank you very much. Actually, I only want to use the up to down view and not a 3D view. Anyway, thanks a lot.